# Иерархия ссылок Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется своя (не twentytwentyone) тема Wordpress.
Необходимо обработать вывод списка постов рубрики/подрубрики с помощью файлов category.php, archive.php и т.д.
Ссылки иерархичны, т.е. выглядят следующим образом:

`/blog` - основная рубрика

`/blog/movies` - подрубрика рубрики *blog*

`/blog/movies/post1` - пост подрубрики *movies*

В Wordpress в постоянных ссылках указано `/%category%/%postname%`. Префикс указан как
`.`

Проблема: Файл *category.php* перехватывает ссылки формата `/blog` и `/movies`, но необходимо, чтобы он перехватывал ссылку формата `/blog/movies/`

Comment: а ссылку формата /blog как вы предполагаете обрабатывать?

Comment: @slovenberg а сам код, как Вы сейчас получаете категории?